# How to have chrome automatically remove a <div> element?

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

The approach given by this [post](https://superuser.com/a/1485353/1093117) works well that have chrome automatically remove html header. Although it fails when dealing with banners.

here is the html code for the banner

```
<div id="js-gdpr-consent-banner">
```

here is the code running in TamperMonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @grant        none
// @include        http://*
// @include        https://*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
    elems[0].parentNode.removeChild(elems[0]);
    var elems1 = document.getElementsById('js-gdpr-consent-banner');
    elems1[0].parentNode.removeChild(elems1[0]);
})();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be only one element with that Id, you should be using getElementById (not pluralized, it doesn't exist)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

And depending on the version of browser/javascript you can just do elems1.remove() to delete it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

The full code would be something like

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @grant        none
// @include        http://*
// @include        https://*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
    elems.item(0).remove();
    var elems1 = document.getElementById('js-gdpr-consent-banner');
    elems1.remove();
})();
```